# How an online service scales high-demanding storage capacity?

Tags: storage

I was wondering how online services which have a high demand for storage capacity - scale physically? (hardware)

Let's assume a service needs to store 1000TB of data, at one geographic location, with the ability to scale. Is there a common way to approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways, depending on the infrastructure of the application.  Network Attached Storage (NAS) solutions from companies like NetApp are common.  For other applications, enterprise SAN arrays may be appropriate using iSCSI or FibreChannel.

There are even more creative folks on the hardware side, such as that detailed in [this blog post from Backblaze](http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/) about their Storage Pods, 67TB of NAS for less than $8k (probably even less now with falling drive prices).

Other considerations include redundancy and backup.  Performance considerations may affect whether one uses enterprise arrays with SAS drives, or commodity SATA hardware.

Obviously any additional hardware comes with considerations for power, space, and connectivity.  These may be handled by the company if they run their own datacenter, or they may be handled by another company via colocation or a fully managed environment.

Comment: Those pods are awesome phoebus, thanks for the link share!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response - I actually thought that an online service implies using a service of an existing datacenter? - Regards performance, most of the operation is reading - serving clients. Let's assume there are lots of cache-servers for clients, to take the load off from the primary storage, so I guess we might as well assume minimum performance needs. Let's take a popular service such as Youtube for example?

Comment: Some online services have their own datacenters.  Youtube certainly does (well, probably its parent company, Google).  I just meant that considerations are split up if the datacenter isn't the responsibility of the company looking for storage.

Comment: You'd have to ask Google what they use, but knowing them, they probably have a custom solution based on massive amounts of commodity hardware, since that's how they run their search/ad business.

Comment: @phoebus: So if Google chooses commodity hardware for such requirement, I suppose it's a common decision for similar demanding services? (I assume the link you gave for 'backblaze' is an example of a commodity solution)

Comment: @Doori it's a common choice for companies who can afford to sculpt their own front-end system to support a commodity back-end system. Backblaze for example serves everything up via HTTP and they've written that whole stack that sits between web users and the storage pods. Using commodity components isn't feasible if you don't have the resources to develop a front-end. In a few cases you may find a software stack to support it (e.g. OpenFiler). But these don't scale as well as the bespoke software.

Comment: If its video content with heavy reads more so than less the core of that technology is not always to invest the capital in the hardware and factor the risk as well as the operating expense but rather a process of working with an expert in that business model.  It can be a difficult task to maintain the core of the business and have to also become an IT shop managing an infrastructure, putting all of the eggs in one basket.  Check with a CDN partner, such as Akamai - I do a lot of work with them they are a leader when it comes to content delivery. Also Brightcove if its video streaming

Answer (score 0):

There is a always room for growth when design is properly placed
I would focus on 2 primary factors in consideration.

The facility at which this content resides, primary power and cooling since we have not spoke yet about the performance needs or bandwidth, this storage will need ample power and air conditioning at proper temperatures.

Secondary would be the technology solution used to store this data.  An enterprise SAN device? Commodity white boxes or a combination of both and some DAS enclosures.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response - I just commented on the following question

Comment: your welcome, anytime.  feel free to reach out to me if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

besides the neat hardware boxes mentioned by [phoebus](https://serverfault.com/questions/196305/how-an-online-service-scales-high-demanding-storage-capacity/196314#196314), you need some software to tie it up.  One way is to run iSCSI on each box and mount them all as a big filesystem (ZFS or XFS would be happy to handle all the PetaBytes), but it quickly becomes a management nightmare and a bottleneck.

A much more scalable and failure resistant is to use a 'object store' system.  There are several ones available, both proprietary and Open Source, but the ones i'm leaning to are [mogileFS](http://danga.com/mogilefs/) and [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.com/), the first one for simplicity and the latter for maturity (and POSIX compliancy).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I was wondering if there's anything wrong with treating each box as a whole, which being identified by it's internally assigned IP? which means, each database record will have an identifier of the IP, and that way it will access a specific storage-box for the relevant path/file?

Comment: @Doory Bar: absolutely. in fact, that's the start of those object-store systems i mentioned.  of course, there's a lot more than that: redundancy, management, load balance, etc.  i did write my own store a long time ago, then networked block storage became affordable and replaced most of it with AoE+LVM+XFS, and currently plan to replace the rest with GlusterFS.